# sharepoint 2013 document library URL change

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library

I have a document library(**Lib_A**) and the files in this library are referred in Pages. I had a requirement to modify the URL of **Lib_A** to **Lib_A_Old** and then create a new document library with the same name as **Lib_A**.

Once done, all the URLs (in pages library) pointing to the files in old **Lib_A** are automatically changed to **Lib_A_Old**.  I dont want this change and would like these urls to be **/sitename/Lib_A/documentName** rather than **/sitename/Lib_A_old/documentName**.  Is this the sharepoint behaviour or is there anything that can be done to retain the URL referenece?

Comment: I am currently doing test in my SharePoint and will give an update as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert link from SharePoint, after you change the URL of the document library, all the URLs (in pages library) pointing to the files in old Lib_A will be automatically changed to Lib_A_Old.

As an workaround, choose insert link from Address:

[image]